# Testing a form with missing elements gives me an error with is ErrorController.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-form

I'm doing some testing to my login form but I notice that If I dont send all the expected parameters, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object in C:\demo\application\controllers\ErrorController.php on line 47

for example this test code gives me error:

```
public function testLoginPage ()
{
    $this->request->setMethod('POST')->setPost(
    array('username' => 'foobar');

    $this->dispatch('/usuario/login');
}
```

But if I send all the elements everything works as expected:

```
public function testLoginPage ()
{
    $this->request->setMethod('POST')->setPost(
    array('username' => 'foobar','password' => 'secret');
    $this->dispatch('/usuario/login');
}
```

Is this normal? I dont understard why I get an error on `ErrorController.php`, where is the connection?

(I thought that maybe is something that not loading, but why is it working when all elemnts are?)

Any help understanding this will be appreciated.

Thanks

**Update:**

I just change to an incorrect password for db database in the application.ini and that gives me the same error. Now I dont even think is the form but maybe some call at the bootstart that is depending to the Zend_Auth identity. But what means that `Fatal error: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object`? how to load that object?

Comment: You have some mismatched parenthesis in the code above.

Comment: Can you please add the lines 40-54 of ErrorController.php (and indicate which is 47)?

Comment: I see at the ErrorController that the lines are: $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
if (!$bootstrap->hasResource('Log')), how can I check if the bookstrap is loading correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what `getInvokeArg()` returns when the bootstrap doesn't load correct, but if you expect it to return an object, check that `is_object($bootstrap)` is true before using `$bootstrap`.

Answer (score 4):

Read the error message you get. You're calling `hasResource()` on a non-object in `ErrorController.php`. Your error controller is broken, but that's not really the issue here.

The issue is that there's an exception being thrown somewhere (possibly in your form, bootstrap, or anywhere really) which triggers the error controller. Fix or disable the error handler to get the exception message and stack trace to find out your problem.

To disable the error handler

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setParam('noErrorHandler', true);
```